# Way to eliminate DISTINCT in this query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

This query returns the correct SUM, but its duplicating itself:

```
SELECT [GrandTotal] = (total1 + total2)
FROM (SELECT(SELECT SUM([Total]) [total1] FROM [ooc].[RentalRevenue2] WHERE [CheckOut] >= '2015-01-01' AND [CheckOut] < '2015-06-30' AND [CampaignName] NOT LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%') as total1,
            (SELECT SUM([Total]) [total2] FROM [ooc].[Revenue2] WHERE [DateConfirmationReceived] >= '2015-01-01' AND [DateConfirmationReceived] < '2015-06-30' AND [CampaignName] LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%') as total2
      FROM [ooc].[Revenue2]) T
```

I can eliminate this behavior by adding DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [GrandTotal] = (total1 + total2)
FROM (SELECT(SELECT SUM([Total]) [total1] FROM [ooc].[RentalRevenue2] WHERE [CheckOut] >= '2015-01-01' AND [CheckOut] < '2015-06-30' AND [CampaignName] NOT LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%') as total1,
            (SELECT SUM([Total]) [total2] FROM [ooc].[Revenue2] WHERE [DateConfirmationReceived] >= '2015-01-01' AND [DateConfirmationReceived] < '2015-06-30' AND [CampaignName] LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%') as total2
      FROM [ooc].[Revenue2]) T
```

I don't think this is the correct way of executing this SUM query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(Total)
FROM    (
        SELECT  total
        FROM    Revenue2
        WHERE   DateConfirmationReceived >= '2015-01-01'
                AND DateConfirmationReceived < '2015-06-30'
                AND CampaignName LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  total
        FROM    RentalRevenue2
        WHERE   checkout >= '2015-01-01'
                AND checkout < '2015-06-30'
                AND CampaignName NOT LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%'
        ) q
```

Comment: This works great. I would have possible NULL values so I went with this solution although both solutions could be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Your two subqueries that perform `SUM` operations don't appear to have any relationship to the `SELECT ... FROM [ooc].[Revenue2]` query that contains them. But, because they are located in that construct, there will be one row in the output for every row in `[ooc].[Revenue2]`. Based on what I see here, you can safely simplify the query to the following:

```
SELECT [GrandTotal] = 
       (SELECT SUM([Total]) [total1] 
          FROM [ooc].[RentalRevenue2] 
         WHERE [CheckOut] >= '2015-01-01' 
           AND [CheckOut] < '2015-06-30'
           AND [CampaignName] NOT LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%') +
       (SELECT SUM([Total]) [total2]
          FROM [ooc].[Revenue2]
         WHERE [DateConfirmationReceived] >= '2015-01-01' 
           AND [DateConfirmationReceived] < '2015-06-30'
           AND [CampaignName] LIKE '%Non-Cancellable%')
```

As pointed out by @Quassnoi, if either of these subqueries results in no rows, the final result will be `NULL`. This can be avoided with `ISNULL(..., 0)` wrapped around each subquery. I will leave this up to the OP as they may know whether such a result is even possible.

Comment: not sure if it's the author's intent or not, but if either query returns nothing, the total result will be `NULL`, even if the other query returns something.

Comment: @Quassnoi: fair. I'll mention using `ISNULL` to avoid that situation.